# I want the column headings in an HTML table to be printed vertically

Tags: html

I want this table

```
id     name       country
--     -------    -------

1       John        America
2       Smith        Mexico
3       Khan        India
```

to be printed like this

```
id            1             2           3
name        John          Smith       Khan
country     America       Mexico      India
```

in HTML.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>John</td>
<td>America</td>
</tr>
```

How should I modify the above code to get that output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `th` for the headers regardless of whether they run horizontally or vertically. You can have both a row header and a column header in the same table. You can also add the optional `scope` attribute which improves accessibility, gives you a hook so you can style them differently with CSS, and makes the meaning clear for maintainability.

The `scope` attribute specifies the set of data cells for which the current header cell provides header information. The `row` value provides header information for the rest of the row that contains it. And the `col` value provides header information for the rest of the column that contains it.

[Read more about the scope attribute.](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">id</th>
        <th scope="col">1</th>
        <th scope="col">2</th>
        <th scope="col">3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th scope="row">name</th>
       <td>John</td>
       <td>Smith</td>
       <td>Khan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">country</th>
        <td>America</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>India</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**: Example CSS

```
th[scope=row] { color: green }
th[scope=col] { color: blue }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
     <table>
     <tr>
     <th>id</th><td>1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <th>name</th><td>John</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <th>country</th><td>America</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this question, and I dont there is no way to make it by css.. You can acheive it by update your html code to like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>name</th>
       <td>John</td>
       <td>Akhil</td>
       <td>Sas</td>
    </tr>
        <th>country</th>
        <td>America</td>
        <td>India</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very easy with CSS.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>America</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Khan</td>
      <td>India</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
@media print {
  tr { display: inline-block; }
  th, td { display: block; }
  }
```

**Result**

[image]